# How to make multiple circles intersect smoother when I am drawing with canvas

Tags: flutter, canvas, mapbox

I want to achieve an effect similar to the one shown in the following image, which is a screenshot of my previous use of Zenly. I infer that the effect of intersecting circles should be optimized?

Expected effect

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzJoT.png)

So my understanding is that he draws each data point into a circle. If two circles do not intersect, draw circles independently. If two circles intersect and X | Y are equal, draw more straight lines as edges (dashed lines in the figure). If you do not want to wait, handle the smooth transition of the intersecting circles separately.